# Add-in not working in Outlook Web App in classic mode when loaded in Safari

Tags: outlook, safari, outlook-web-app, office-store

Hi Office 365 (Microsoft 365) Team,

I'd like to ask for your help with the certification process. My Outlook add-in has failed certification with only one issue:

> **1120.3.2.5 Online Safari**
>
> The add-in is not working in Outlook Web App in Modern & classic mode when loaded in Safari (13.1)
>
> The following error appears at launch: "Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator.".

I have *successfully* tested the add-in with

- different Safari versions (13.0 and 13.1), and
- email accounts (corporate Azure Exchange server and Outlook Live (@outlook.hu))
- (also in Chrome, just to be sure)

on the following URLs:

- https://outlook.office.com/owa (modern mode)
- https://outlook.office.com/owa?path=classic (classic mode)

My add-in's task panel has a Content-Security-Policy ruleset (frame-ancestors) applied that allows the html file to be embedded on the following origins:

- https://outlook.office.com/
- https://outlook.office365.com/
- https://outlook.live.com/

Could you please confirm that the certification process is using a OWA that is running on one of these domains? (I could not find any reports of CSP violations in the logs.)

I have no other idea why the add-in is running on my computers but still failing the certification.

The following Stack Overflow questions may be related:

- [Clarify what is safari classic mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666419/clarify-what-is-safari-classic-mode)
- [Office 365 add-in: Content Security Policy issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287242/office-365-add-in-content-security-policy-issues)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Comment: @piet.t it is rather unfortunate that the developers are redirected here by Microsoft to ask questions about the development and the certification processes.This question is mainly focused on the undocumented testing scenarios, and making an easy-to-find Google result for developers in the same situation to find out what may be the problem with their submission.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that certification is using one of the domains you have listed above.